# Retrieving images from DB in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

I have a database filled with data, when I retrieve the data the image comes as raw data. I know that I have to save them in public directory when I upload but, is there any chance to show these images since they are already saved in database and I just want to display them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What format is the data in your database?

If it is base64 you can display it like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ $user->image_data }}" alt="title" />
```

Or if its not base64 encoded yet:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ base64_encode($user->image_data) }}" alt="title" />
```

Note: The browser does not cache images rendered like this.

Comment: Hi Björn, Thank you for your reply, 
I use Blob